# Django How to get GET parameters in template

Tags: python, django, getparameter

I'm working on a django project.
I'm wondering how to get GET parameters in template so that I can make corresponding tab active.
I tried the code below, but it didn't work.

```
<a class="list-group-item {% if '?q=' in request.path %}active{% endif %}" href="{% url 'blah'%}"> Foo </a>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: get it in `view` and send it as parameter in `render(..., context={"active":True})` and use it `{% if active %}active{% endif %}` or set it as `context={"extra_class": "active"}` or `context={"extra_class": ""}` and set without `if` as `"list-group-item {{ extra_class }}"`

Comment: @furas Could you have a look at this question as well?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68341820/how-to-align-decimal-point-of-price-in-django-template

Comment: @furas Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it in `view` and send it as parameter in `render`

```
active = ('?q=' in request.path)

render(..., context={"active": active})
```

and use it in template

```
class="list-group-item {% if active %}active{% endif %}"
```

Or get it as

```
if '?q=' in request.path:
   extra_class = "active"
else:
   extra_class = ""

render(..., context={"extra_class": extra_class})
```

and set in template without `if`

```
class="list-group-item {{ extra_class }}"
```

---

BTW:

You could get it also as

```
query = request.GET.get('q', '')

render(..., context={"query": query})
```

and use it in template to set class and to display query

```
You search: {{ query }}

class="list-group-item {% if query %}active{% endif %}"
```