# How to align decimal point of price in django template?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to display amount of money a user spent in a table.
I want the display amount to look neat, but it looks like below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOpQ3.png

I want their dot to be on the black straight line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sir is it inside the table or something else can you please the screenshot of the full page

Comment: Right align everything.

Comment: it is job for `CSS` - `text-align: right`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution of your answer
you can replace the price with your dyanmic price of django
here is picture
[image]

here is the html

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
          <div style="display: flex;justify-content:space-between"><span>$</span><span>18.75</span></div>
          <div style="display: flex;justify-content:space-between"><span>$</span><span>18.75</span></div>
          <div style="display: flex;justify-content:space-between"><span>$</span><span>18.75</span></div>
          <div style="display: flex;justify-content:space-between"><span>$</span><span>.75</span></div>
          <div style="display: flex;justify-content:space-between"><span>$</span><span>784.75</span></div>
      </div>
```